# java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Structure of database
```

[image]

At first , while testing when the user is logged in or fully registered there is no exception or error  but when the user signs out and reopen the app the app crashes . the logcat is basically pointing the error on this :

```
 UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
```

But if i change the **currentUserID** to **Users** .. the app stops crashing and runs smoothly but it doesnot loads up the username and the profile image that is located in the naviagation drawer.

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView postlist;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser FirebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference  UsersRef;
    private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
    private ImageButton AddNewPostButton;
    private TextView NavProfileUserName;
    String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
            currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
        }




        mToolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
       actionBarDrawerToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
       AddNewPostButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_new_post_button);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
       actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
        NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_full_name);

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")){
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                }if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
            { UserMenuSelector(item);

                return false;
            }
        });
        AddNewPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToPostActivity();

            }
        });
    }

    private void SendUserToPostActivity() {
        Intent addNewPostIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class);
        startActivity(addNewPostIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }else{
            CheckUserExistance();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistance()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)){
                      sendUserToSetupActivity();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });
    }

    private void sendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();

    }

    private void sendUserToLoginActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
         loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         startActivity(loginIntent);
         finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after signout `mFirebaseUser` gets null value so this `currentUserID` value also gets null to avoid nullpointerexception do null check before you use `currentUserID` like below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private RecyclerView postlist;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser FirebaseUser;
private DatabaseReference  UsersRef;
private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
private ImageButton AddNewPostButton;
private TextView NavProfileUserName;
String currentUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
    }




    mToolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
   actionBarDrawerToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
   AddNewPostButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_new_post_button);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
   actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
    NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
    NavProfileUserName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_full_name);

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
      // replace below code
     if (mFirebaseUser != null) {

    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {   if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")){
                String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
            }if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile name do not exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    }else{
     sendUserToLoginActivity();
    }

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        { UserMenuSelector(item);

            return false;
        }
    });
    AddNewPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SendUserToPostActivity();

        }
    });
}

private void SendUserToPostActivity() {
    Intent addNewPostIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class);
    startActivity(addNewPostIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        sendUserToLoginActivity();
    }else{
        CheckUserExistance();
    }
}

private void CheckUserExistance()
{
    final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
      UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)){
                  sendUserToSetupActivity();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
}

private void sendUserToSetupActivity() {
    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
    setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(setupIntent);
    finish();

}

private void sendUserToLoginActivity()
{
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
     loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
     startActivity(loginIntent);
     finish();

}
```

**OR** you can check directly here also

```
 if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        currentUserID = mFirebaseUser.getUid();
    }else{
        sendUserToLoginActivity();
    }
```

Comment: showed the null pointer  exception on:             
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

Comment: happy to help you mate!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting `null` in `currentUserId` and then passing `null` to firebase. may be you are not getting `user id` make sure that user is logged in and then check that you are getting `user` id from firebase or not . if you are getting `user id` from firebase then try this .

```
UsersRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new 
       ValueEventListener(){ }
```

and make sure that all keys in your User Model class is public , i worked on firebase for about a month regularly and i faced many issues like this .

Comment: exactly .. i did the same for the previous time by changing it to users . it solved the null pointer exception but it didnot load the username and the profile image of the user in the navigation drawer

Comment: exactly because your current user Id is not yet written inside Users that means that user current user id is not child of Users that is why you are receiving null exception because you are referencing user id that is not there yet or it is null , but on the other hand if you reference Users you will not receive null exception because Users key will always be there in database tree

Answer (score 1):

If you check I believe you don't have any logged in user that's why you are getting `null` value in `currentUserID`.

You are checking if user is logged in or not in `OnStart()`, you have to check that in onCreate() also. Because in activity lifecycle `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`.

Here is how your onCreate function  should look:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        sendUserToLoginActivity();
    }else{
        CheckUserExistance();
    }
    //Your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()` because when you are signing out the user, you aren't sending him to a login activity and that's why this error. The simplest way to solve this is to use a listener. Let's assume you have two activities, the `LoginActivity` and the `MainActivity`. The listener that can be created in the `LoginActivity` should look like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

This basically means that if the user is logged in, skip the `LoginActivity` and go to the `MainActivity`.

Instantiate the `FirebaseAuth` object:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

And start listening for changes in your `onStart()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

In the `MainActivity`, you should do the same thing:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
```

Which basically means that if the user is not logged in, skip the `MainActivity` and go to the `LoginActivity`. In this activity you should do the same thing as in the `LoginActivity`, you should start listening for changes in the `onStart()`.

In this way, you'll never get an error like that again.

Comment: Have you also tried my solution above, does it work?